# Python - data frame columns rename with capital letter after the '.'

Tags: python, pandas

I have some columns that follow the pattern 'abc.def' and I'm trying to change it to 'abcDef' with a function. I can do it with `df.rename(columns={'abc.def': 'abcDef'}, inplace = True)` but looking for a more generic approach that can be applied to different data frames. I did it for the simple string and I do not know how to apply it to the column names. I have tried to get column names to the list and append the function to the list but that did not work either.

My df is:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
            
            
data = {'end.date': ['01/10/2020 15:23', '01/10/2020 16:31', '01/10/2020 16:20', '01/10/2020 11:00'],
                  'start.date': ['01/10/2020 13:38', '01/10/2020 14:49', '01/10/2020 14:30','01/10/2020 14:30']
                  }
            
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['end.Date','start.date'])

# below is my go at the text.             
text = 'abs.d'
splitFilter = re.compile('([.!?]\s*)')
splitColumnName = splitFilter.split(text)
print(splitColumnName)
        
final = ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in splitColumnName])
final = final.replace('.', '')
print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like that ?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
            
            
data = {'end.date': ['01/10/2020 15:23', '01/10/2020 16:31', '01/10/2020 16:20', '01/10/2020 11:00'],
                  'start.date': ['01/10/2020 13:38', '01/10/2020 14:49', '01/10/2020 14:30','01/10/2020 14:30']
                  }
            
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['end.Date','start.date'])

# below is my go at the text.   
def formatColumn(column) :
  splitFilter = re.compile('([.!?]\s*)')
  splitColumnName = splitFilter.split(column)
          
  final = ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in splitColumnName])
  final = final.replace('.', '')
  return final[0].lower() + final[1:] 

df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, [formatColumn(c) for c in df.columns])))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You could improve your answer with a few explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I used the answers from @Arne and from @LeMorse and compiled what I needed. Thanks again!

```
import pandas as pd
import re
            
            
data = {'end.date': ['01/10/2020 15:23', '01/10/2020 16:31', '01/10/2020 16:20', '01/10/2020 11:00'],
                  'start.date': ['01/10/2020 13:38', '01/10/2020 14:49', '01/10/2020 14:30','01/10/2020 14:30']
                  }
            
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['end.Date','start.date'])

# below is my go at the text.   
def formatColumn(column) :
  splitFilter = re.compile('([.!?]\s*)')
  splitColumnName = splitFilter.split(column)
          
  final = ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in splitColumnName])
  final = final.replace('.', '')
  return final[0].lower() + final[1:] 

df.columns = [formatColumn(col) for col in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your code to transform an individual string into a function and then apply this function to every column name, e.g. with a list comprehension:

```py
def camelCase(text):
    splitFilter = re.compile('([.!?]\s*)')
    splitColumnName = splitFilter.split(text)
    final = ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in splitColumnName])
    final = final.replace('.', '')
    return final

df.columns = [camelCase(col) for col in df.columns]
```

Note that currently your code capitalizes the first letter too.

Comment: His code was not correct as it was not doing the correct thing he was seeking for i.e for abc.def instead of generating abcDef his code was generating AbcDef, and you did the same thing so your answer is not correct

Comment: @Doodle You should read my answer before claiming that it were not correct. Then you might discover that it is pointing out the very thing you are complaining about. The question was not "please write a complete solution for me", which by the way would violate SO rules, but more specifically how to apply the transformation to all the column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
def splitAndRenameColumns(df, splitSignal):
 # get all the columns in a list
 columnNameList = df.columns.values.tolist()
 # create a map to rename columns
 # mapping is old.columnname : newColumnname
 newColNames = {}
 # loop pver all column names
 for clm in columnNameList :
    # split the column names on "provided split signal i.e dot in this case"
    tempStore = clm.split(splitSignal)
    # store the first word before dot in temparory string  
    newString = tempStore[0]
    # loop over all other string values we got after splitting  
    for index in range(1,len(tempStore)):
        # capitalise first character to upper case and concatenate all the strings 
        newString += tempStore[index][0].upper()+tempStore[index][1:]
    # create the mapping 
    # i.e {'end.Date.gate': 'endDateGate', 'start.date.bate': 'startDateBate'}
    newColNames[clm] = newString
 return newColNames


df = df.rename(columns=splitAndRenameColumns(df, "."))
print(df)
```

It's almost similar to other answers but It's more generic in-terms of split signals and explains the process with comments clearly.
Let me know if you still need more comments on the code